# Accessing char pointer at offset 0 in struct via casting for printing with printf

Tags: c, struct, casting

I have a structure and want to pass it as an argument to `printf` by casting it to `(char*)`. But I get gibberish output. I have learned that the pointer to the structure is also an pointer to its first member so I thought this typecast should work.

Why it doen't?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct str {
    char *s;
} str;

int main(void)
{
    str s;
    s.s = "Hello World!";
    printf("%s\n", (char *) &s);
}
```

Output:

```
(random bytes)
```

Comment: Try `*(char**)&s` instead.

Comment: @n.m. Works. Thank you. Thought it would be less writing needed. Why is `*(char**)&s` not the same as `(char*)` as this dereferences the "double pointer" to `char *` isn't it?

Comment: One of these things works and the other doesn't, so they cannot possibly be the same. `printf` wants a pointer that points to characters. `&s` (however you cast it) points to `s`, but `s` does not contain characters, it contains a pointer which points to characters. To get to that pointer, you need to dereference `&s`, suitably cast.

Comment: BIG AHHHH effect on me right now. Never realized a char pointer is interpreted like that.

Comment: @mortytheshorty `&s` in your original code is "address of `s`", which is also "address of `s.s`" because, as you noted, "the pointer to the structure is also an pointer to its first member".  **But** `s.s` is a `char *` pointer, and taking an address of a `char *` results in a `char **`.  `printf( "...%s...", ...)` expects to receive the **value** of a `char *`, not its address.

Comment: mortytheshorty, [Moral of the Story](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/moral): avoid casting.  It tends to hide problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this call of `printf`

```
printf("%s\n", (char *) &s);
```

the value of the expression `&s` points to the data member `s` of the object of the structure type.  So the call of `printf` trying to interpret the memory occupied by the data member `s` itself as a string.

Instead you need to write

```
printf("%s\n", *(char **) &s);
```

Comment: Also thanks to you but n.m's comment above somehow made it clearer for me. Now I can follow your explaination too.

Answer (score 2):

It would work if the string was a part of the struct, not reference to it. If you change the code to:

```
typedef struct str {
    char s[24];
} str;

int main(void)
{
    str s = {"Hello World!"};
    printf("%s\n", (char *) &s);
}
```

It will work as you expected.
https://godbolt.org/z/r17PPY9z3

I think you have a problem understanding the difference between a pointer and an array.

BTW avoid pointer punning.